# Translating UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uidatepicker

I want to translate UIDatePicker. I use it for date and time and now it's day, hour, minute

[image: enter image description her]

I want to translate for example -> Fri Oct 26 to my language.

I can't find how to do this. Maybe someone could help me

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to. System controls have builtin localication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localizing depends on the iPhone region format settings (set it in the simulator or the device). Check out these answers:

[Can I localize a UIDatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151335/can-i-localize-a-uidatepicker)

[UIDatePicker - Problem Localizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894161/uidatepicker-problem-localizing)

[iphone uidatepicker localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165859/iphone-uidatepicker-localization)